# net core 2.0 automapper set identity property to null

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I am doing a `net core 2.0` Application with `Entity Framework`.

I am using `AutoMapper` to copy data from one entity to another.

```html
public class Entity1
    {
     public int OrderID { get; set; }
     public int MarketID { get; set; }
     }

public class Entity2
    {
    [Key]
     public int MarketOrderID { get; set; }
     public int OrderID { get; set; }
     public int MarketID { get; set; }
     }
```

The property `Entity2.MarketOrderID` is defined as identity.

AutoMapper is simple.

```
 CreateMap<Entity1, Entity2>()
```

I save Entity2 to database like this.

```html
  public void Insert(Entity1 item)
{
  Entity2 _entity2 = new Entity2();
  Mapper.Map<Entity1, Entity2>(item, _entity2);
  _context.Entity2.Add(_entity2);
  _context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

The problem I have is that `Entity2.MarketOrderID` is set to zero (0).
And on line `_context.SaveChanges();` gave me an error because of that.HI,

I am doing an Net Core 2.0 Application. I am using Entity Framework.

I have two entities and I using 
It should be `null`.

I tried to set in null setting in mapping

```
.ForMember(x => x.MarketOrderID, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But it does not work.

How can I set Identity to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set identity to null as it's primary key. You should try to keep your mapping ignore for id property. Try setting id for auto increment with fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .Property(f => f.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Or with annotations:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int BlogId { get; set; }
```

Doc's -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties

If you change your id to GUID you could try:

```
CreateMap<Entity1, Entity2>()
     .ForMember(x => x.MarketOrderID, m => m.MapFrom(p => Guid.NewGuid()))
```